# What are possible functions assigned on decision nodes for decision tree prediction?

Tags: decision-trees

In Decision Tree or Random Forest, each tree has a collection of decision nodes (in which each node has a threshold value) and a class labels (or regression values).

I know that threshold values are used for comparison with a corresponding feature value. As far as I know, the comparison is performed either "<", ">"  or "==" predicate.
Anything else for the functions taking threshold value and a feature value as inputs??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a binary split, there are only three possible operations (or arguably only two if you consider one-hot encoding). Any other kind of split would simply not be binary. Almost every tree-based model is restricted to *binary* splits, due to the combinatorial explosion when considering ternary or even more complex splits.

Of course you could write your own algorithm that uses recursive non-binary splits. Beware though that you'll be facing the same difficulty that has led the vast majority of algorithms to be limited to strictly binary splits.

Have a look at [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12187/176202).